# comparing two strings in bash issue

Tags: string, bash, syntax, compare

I have a bash script like this:

```
vartest=(`/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -h 10.0.1.143 -t -p 6432 -d gpperfmon -c "select delete_oldest_db_test();"`)
echo ${vartest[2]}


what_to_delete=${vartest[2]}

if ["$what_to_delete" == "Nothing"]; then
echo "Nothing to delete"
else
dropdb -h 10.0.1.143 -p 6432 -U postgres ${vartest[0]}

fi
```

But when I run it I get this:

line 7: [Nothing: command not found

I've tried to compare using quotes, double quotes, no quotes at all, and nothing seems to work..
The issue is in this line:

```
  if ["$what_to_delete" == "Nothing"]; then
```

Thanks

Comment: Always first test your broken script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was such thing, I'm kinda new to bash scripting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax issue, thanks Gilles for sharing the link to check script.

I didn't have a space between the braket and the double quote..

it was a matter of adding the missing space before and after:

```
if [ "$what_to_delete" = "Nothing" ]; then
```

Comment: While using bash, you should prefer `[[ ]]` way. [[ is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the [ command. See <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031> and <http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals>. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend [[.